# Add Objects From One View Controller To An Array On Another View Controller

Tags: iphone, ios

I have been trying to figure this out for a while and not coming up with a solution. I have a view controller with a table and the first cell of the table is allocated for a button called "Add Friends". When clicked, it takes you to another view controller with a list of contacts in a table. When you click on a person, it goes back to the other view controller and adds the selected person. This is what I have so far.

ContactsViewController.m

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
FirstViewController *newVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"newVCSegue"];

newVC.peopleArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

Person *user = [contactsList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSArray *userKeys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"FirstName", @"LastName", nil];
NSArray *userObjects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:user.firstName, user.lastName, nil];
NSDictionary *userDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:userObjects forKeys:userKeys];
[newVC.peopleArray addObject:userDictionary];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:newVC animated:YES];

[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

FirstViewController.h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *peopleArray;
```

FirstViewController.m

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
//...
if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        contactName.text = @"Add Person";
        imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"plus-icon.png"];
} else {
NSString *firstName = [[peopleArray objectAtIndex:(indexPath.row)-1] objectForKey:@"firstName"];
NSString *lastName = [[peopleArray objectAtIndex:(indexPath.row)-1] objectForKey:@"lastName"];
contactName.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", firstName, lastName];
}
return cell;
}
```

This lets me add one friend so far and if I decided to add another to the list, it replaces the first friend added.

Comment: Did you synthesize peopleArray ?? If not, synthesize it and use it as self.peopleArray instead of peopleArray...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's basically happening is every time you select a new contact, you're recreating the array in the first view controller, hence it is replacing things. You ideally want to try and avoid getting the FirstViewController using the storyboard like that as well, it's pretty bad practice and may well lead to various problems later.

What I'd suggest in this situation is creating a protocol (look at the delegate pattern). This way, what you'd have is :

- Use taps "Add Contact"
- Contacts list appears, and FirstViewController is set as the delegate
- User taps contact to add them
- ContactsViewController informs the delegate of the user that was selected
- FirstViewController adds the user, and dismissed the view controller

This is generally the approach you'd take, and it's pretty simple to implement. Start with the protocol

```
@protocol ContactsDelegate
-(void) contactsViewController:(ContactsViewController *)vc didSelectContact:(Person *)person;
@end
```

Then, make your FirstViewController implement this protocol. To do this, in your header file, in the angle brackets after the name (< >) add `ContactsDelegate`

In the implementation of FirstViewController, add the new method of the contacts delegate.

In your ContactsViewController.h file, add

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSObject<ContactsDelegate> *delegate;
```

Then when you display your contacts view controller, set the delegate

```
userVc.delegate = self;
[self presentModalViewController:userVc];
```

Then, in the user view controllers `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`, simply inform the delegate that you've selected that person

```
[delegate contactsViewController:self didSelectContact:[contactsList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

And lastly, in your FirstViewController, in the delegate method you added, we need to ADD the user to the list, not re-create the list

```
[peopleArray addObject:person];
```

And that should do what you're after :)

Comment: You are freaking awesome!! Thank you!! This worked perfectly. :)

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you are instantiating a new FirstViewController every time you select a contact in the ContactsViewController. Instead, you should reference the original FirstViewController (perhaps save it before transitioning to ContactsViewController), and use this reference to add the contact to the original array `[original.people addObject:userDict]`. As long as you make sure to reload the table, this should work.